# how to pass JVM argument ito CloudHub application

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb, cloudhub

We have a Mule 4 code deployed in CloudHub and we need to pass -Doracle.net.disableOob=true to this Mule runtime.
What are the steps to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting it in the properties tab of the application in Runtime Mánager. Just name of the property oracle.net.disableOob and value true.

Having said that, this looks as a database connection property and may only work if set at the connector level.

Comment: I was checking at connection but could not find any such options.

Comment: what do you mean by connection? do you want to check connection logs of any connector?

Comment: He is trying to set a configuration that seems related to the Oracle DB JDBC driver rather than a JVM property.